# Find planetary temperature

Tags: climate, temperature, greenhouse-gases

I’ve asked this on Worldbuilding, but can anyone find/make me a formula that can be used to predict the mean temperature of a planet, while factoring in greenhouse effect?

Comment: The website, [Planet Temperature Calculator](https://www.astro.indiana.edu/ala/PlanetTemp/index.html) will calculate this and it includes a Greenhouse factor *G*, which for Earth is 1 & Venus is around 200. The Greenhouse Factor ranges between 0 and 500.

This question, [How to calculate the expected surface temperature of a planet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/how-to-calculate-the-expected-surface-temperature-of-a-planet), on SE Astronomy gives the equation **without** the Greenhouse Factor.

Comment: I use it, as I don’t have a formula for that.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a [zero-dimensional climate model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_model#Zero-dimensional_models). The equation without the Greenhouse effect is simple, though with a lot of simplifications, [one with a very crude, linearized, Greenhouse effect is possible.](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/meteo469/node/137#:%7E:text=In%20this%20very%20simple%20model,model%20as%20%27zero%20dimensional%27.)

Comment: It works. It’s T=((1-a)S/(4eo))^.25, and it gives a planetary temperature for Earth that’s very close to the average temperature of the planet. And S=P/r^2.